# How to add fields to new document onCreate?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to add new fields to a new document after calculation, that I have to do when a new doc is created. But, the field isn't added.

I have deploy this code without any errors but when a new doc is added in this path, nothing happens..

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.test = functions.firestore.document('a/{a.id}/b/{b.id}/c/d')
.onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {
  const data = snapshot.data();
  const userRef = db.doc(`a/${a.id}/b/${b.id}/c/d`);
  var result = 1+2; //just for lighter code example
  return userRef.update({
    result: result
  });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your wildcards are invalid.  You can't have a dot in the wildcard name.  I'm kind of surprised that the Firebase CLI allowed you to deploy this function.  Also, you're not using the wildcards correctly, even if those wildcards were valid.

There is an easier way to get a reference to the document that was just created.  You can use [`snapshot.ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#ref).

```
exports.test = functions.firestore.document('a/{a}/b/{b}/c/d')
.onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {
  var result = 1+2; //just for lighter code example
  return snapshot.ref.update({
    result: result
  });
})
```

If you do want to use the wildcard values, you should use `context.params` instead, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters).